# problem with generating PDF by html2pdf library

Tags: angular, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I'm using html2pdf library in order to generate PDF in my angular app. In one of my components I want to generate part of its html.

```
<div id="InspectionReportPDF" style="width: 190mm" class="export-font-small">
    <div class="top-page d-flex justify-content-center">
      <h1>
        {{ locale.getText("certificate-of-compliance") }}
      </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is part of my html form
and here's my .ts

```
async onInspectionReportClick() {
   setTimeout(() => {
    let element = document.getElementById('InspectionReportPDF');
    console.log('test element', element);
    let opt = {
      pagebreak: { mode: ['css', 'legacy'] },
      margin: [10, 10, 10, 10],

      filename: 'Inspection Report.pdf',
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
      html2canvas: {
        dpi: 192,
        scale: 5,
        letterRendering: true,
        useCORS: true,
      },
      jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
    };
    html2pdf()
      .set(opt)
      .from(element)
      .save()
      .then((res: any) => {});

    }, 10);
  }
```

when click on generating PDF my app freeze and it won't generating PDF I don't have even an error, it just doesn't work

I tried to generate simpler html code

```
<div id="InspectionReportPDF" style="width: 190mm" class="export-font-small"></div>
```

but it didn't work as I expected